# Manage spring dependencies efficiently

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, dependency-management

We have a huge Java project with a lot of modules leading to a lot of dependencies.

Let's say B depends on A (a Spring bean).

In the past time we had situations where

- the "interface" of A was changed and B stopped working in runtime,
- the behaviour of A was changed so B continued working but not as expected.

How to avoid or deal with such situations? I'm interested in processes, software solutions or guidelines.

Comment: You should be accepting an answer ! Or did none of the suggestions work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuous integration and a test suite should be part of the solution. When A changes everything that depends on A gets re-tested.

The next is to make sure what is public (i.e. used outside of its project) is known to be public, so when changes are made everyone who needs to know, knows.
Look at the separation of your teams and code base. Should A and B be handled by the same team? Should they be part of the same code base?

Answer (score 1):

> **We have a huge Java project with a lot of modules leading to a lot of
> dependencies.**

Number1:

according to [Spring Framework Best Practices](http://www.onjava.com/2006/01/25/spring-xml-configuration-best-practices.html):

> Do not abuse dependency injection:
>
> As the last point, Spring ApplicationContext can create Java objects
> for you, but not all Java objects should be created through dependency
> injection. As an example, domain objects should not be created through
> ApplicationContext. Spring is an excellent framework, but, as far as
> the readability and manageability are concerned, the XML-based
> configuration can become an issue when many beans are defined. Overuse
> of dependency injection will make the XML configuration more
> complicated and bloated. Remember, with powerful IDEs, such as Eclipse
> and IntelliJ, Java code is much easier to read, maintain, and manage
> than XML files!

so use dependency injection only in occasion cases and other wise it make your project confusing.

> **I'm interested in processes, software solutions or guidelines.**

if you decide to use dependency injection, there are some other hints:

Number 2:

> Prefer setter injection over constructor injection:
>
> Spring provides three types of dependency injection: constructor
> injection, setter injection, and method injection.
> Constructor injection can ensure that a bean cannot be constructed in
> an invalid state, but setter injection is more flexible and
> manageable, especially when the class has multiple properties and some
> of them are optional.

Number 3:

if B1, B2, ..., Bn depend on A and A has been changed frequently, use a factory class (AFactory) and depend (Bi)s to AFactory bean instead of A bean. then for each changes in creating A bean, only Afactory is affected and other Bi beans don't be changed.

> **the behaviour of A was changed so B continued working but not as expected.**
> you could control these inconvenience by proper integration tests.

also you should design interfaces so that each method have a certain unambiguous behavior. then you assume these methods and behaviors and write B. so changing A's implementation details, don't affect the behavior of B. and it's natural that if you violate the behavior of A, B's behavior is changed. actually it's developer duty to design interfaces carefully and prevent these problem.

Comment: Dependency is already wired by default in Java. What DI should be focusing on is that why can I sometimes not wire with a implementation permanently? I think here "SOMETIMES" is  the  keyword. I believe lots of the Java book missed this point.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to write better unit test cases for the project. To take your example when the component A changes the unit test for B should fail(test for A would fail naturally). I would recommend writing good unit test cases because there really is no other way you can prevent change requests.

Comment: Yeah well so in my opinion you could use a good unit test to cover for the dependencies. You need to use mocks for the dependent modules and that will help you.